# segmentaion fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Hi I'm kind of new to C++ and i had to fill a code. The code should read as many values as given in the first input, afterwards it should compute the triple of the sum of these values.

I tried it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    vector<double> x;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> x[i];
    double v = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        v = 3 * x[i];
    cout << v << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately I end up in a segmentation fault...
Here is the [unfinished code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz3Db.png)

Comment: You're indexing a `vector` out of bounds, consider constructing it with the size `n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vector <double> x;
for (int i =0; i <n ; i++) cin >> x[i] ;
```

`x` here has size zero, so you are putting elements in invalid locations of `x`, which luckily results in a segmentation fault (vector doesn't do any bound checking on `operator[]`, so you are just lucky to have an error).

Either you make the `vector` big enough:

```
vector <double> x(n);
```

Or let it deal with dynamic sizing:

```
vector <double> x;
for (int i =0; i <n ; i++) {
    double d;
    cin >> d ;
    x.push_back(d);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
vector <double> x; //here x has no space for elements
for (int i =0; i <n ; i++) cin >> x[i] ;
```

You do not allocate memory to store elements in vector so `x[i]` is going out of bounds.Use `push_back()` instead.

```
double dummy;
for (int i =0; i <n ; i++)
{ 
    cin >> dummy;
    x.push_back(dummy);
}
```

Comment: I think that your answer is right and it would solve the segmentation fault but its doesnt fit into the set code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz3Db.png

Answer (score 1):

Because in line `vector <double> x;`, you have created a `vector` with `0` size. So there is no space in vector `x` to hold elements.

To correct your code do either of the following:

- Change line `vector <double> x;` to `vector <double> x(n);` **OR**
- Change line `for (int i =0; i <n ; i++) cin >> x[i] ;` to `double temp; for (int i =0; i <n ; i++) {cin >> temp; x.push_back(dummy);}`